# Why is cin, cout, endl, etc. defined inside the std namespace?

Tags: c++

Since we are including the iostream header, what was the need to define cin, cout, endl, etc. inside the std namespace?

What added advantage did this cause?

**Example:**
In C, we use to include stdio header file and used to call printf() and scanf() directly.

(I am aware namespaces is a C++ feature, the example is just to point at my confusion to understand its usage).

**Edit** : What would happen if cin, cout, etc. weren't a part of any namespace and we could just use them directly by just importing the header file. What problems would that cause?

Comment: These are standards commands, why shouldn't they be in the standard (std) namespace?

Comment: Separation of concern perhaps? Separation of symbols? Minimizing name-collisions?

Comment: namespaces are to organize names. You can have `std::foo` and `my_lib::foo` and the names don't clash. Actually I have no clue how C deals with that

Comment: @idclev463035818 it doesn't. Much pain may ensue.

Comment: @idclev463035818 C would have """solved""" the problem with endless names: `std_foo` and `my_lib_foo` ^^ This is why C libraries often prepend every functions names by the library name.

Comment: Are you actually asking: "What is the use of namespaces? Why do they exist?"

Comment: Fun fact, C++ didn't have namespaces from the onset (though they were in the first published standard). There are legacy C++ codebases in the wild today that bear the mark of using the C way to avoid name collisions. It's not pretty.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  I do understand what is the use of namespaces. Like in some comments mentioned above, I understand there maybe more than one definition of foo() and c++ allows us to use namespaces to keep them in different namespace scopes. I am specifically asking why was cin, cout, etc placed inside a namespace? why separate scope in this case?

Comment: @SumaiyaA - What about stuff like `vector`, `list` or `stack`? Do you think it's a good idea for the standard library to hog those in the global namespace? And if it's gonna partition those, why leave other stuff out?

Comment: once you have namespaces you want to use them. `cin` and `cout` are not an expception, why would they be?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica  Let me reframe my question to point out my confusion. What would happen if cin, cout, etc. weren't a part of any namespace and we could just use them directly by just importing the header file. What problems would that cause?

Comment: The problem of having a standard library that is inconsistent in its organization.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica So std was used to group standard functions under one scope for better organization? Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stops pollution of the global namespace. This is a headache in C and a lot of potential pitfalls have grown up: e.g. everything beginning with `str` is reserved in C. Furthermore it allows the C++ standard to define behaviour around `std::` - for example, you are not allowed to add things to `std` with a few exceptions.

By and large then the global namespace is at the mercy of the programmer.

Comment: What are the exceptions?

Comment: @M.A Special specializations of `std::hash`.

Comment: @JulianH [It's a little broader than that](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#2)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on 'It stops pollution of the global namespace?'

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings yeah, the circle drawn by your answer is bigger :)